# Athena interaction with forward slash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I've set up a flow involving Glue, S3 and Athena.

The files are set up as csv with quotations surrounding each value, sample:

"1","London/,United Kingdom","","TRUE" 
"1","United Kingdom","mid","FALSE"

Col A is big int, with the rest as strings

When querying Athena, the results appear as:

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | London | United Kingdom |  |
| 1 | United Kingdom | Mid | FALSE |

This obviously comes down to the forward-slash causing glue, or Athena to ignore the quotation, or the comma which is causing all the results to shift over one. My question is how do I get around this? I really don't want to change my ETL (I've been considering moving the data to dynamodb) as Athena fits every other requirement. I'm hoping there is a setting I can make as to how Athena interprets slashes

my Serde serialization lib is: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe

Serde parameters:
field.delim ,

Comment: Possibly, also include in your question, the values for Output format, Serde serialization lib, Serde parameters from AWS glue table details.

Comment: Please Edit your question and show the DDL that defines your table. You can obtain it by clicking the 3 dots next to the table. Also, where did you run the query -- was it in the Amazon Athena web console?

Comment: Adding in the above from @Pankaj

Comment: sorry @JohnRotenstein I'm not sure how to find the DDL, from what I'm reading it's an either/or if created from a crawler (which I used?) but it is just a standard SQL query. And yes, using the web console.

Comment: @Jake tried simulating; however, could not get what you are seeing. Is the S3 bucket in same AWS environment as Athena? How about if you do not use a crawler and create a table directly from Athena pointing to S3 directory that has the source file?

Comment: Yes they are, sorry I just realised something in my question (I'm trying to replicate using non-sensitive data so was creating a fictious example). The CSV is using \  to ignore commas in the file, but what I'm reading that the escaped by key is '\\' as per this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/lazy-simple-serde.html

Comment: Is there a way I can update the escape key to just be \ ?

Comment: To obtain the DDL (the definition of the table): Find the table in Amazon Athena query editor. Right-click the 3-dots and select "Generate Table DDL". Please paste the DDL into your question so that we can see the parameters for the SerDe. We will also need some actual data that causes the current problem so that we can reproduce your situation and then recommend how to fix it.